# Adding the handling a the parenthesis symbols + handling of functions to lexer/parser

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction

I am studying this example of a very simple programming language with it's compiler :

[how parsers and compilers work](http://parsingintro.sourceforge.net/)

The language has the concept of a variable, and can deal with expressions of the form "variable = v1 + v2" where vi are either already defined variable or numbers (`int`'s and `double`'s). (It can also print.)

For instance, for this piece of code :

```
zozo = 2.3 ;
alpha = 16 ;
beta = 2   ;
gamma = 2 * 3 ;
zozo = zozo + 1 ;
gogo = zozo + gamma ;
```

the following "synthax tree" is produced :

```
    zozo 
    2.3

    alpha
    16

    beta
    2

    gamma
    2
    *
    3

    zozo 
    zozo 
    +
    1

    gogo
    zozo 
    +
    gamma
```

I really don't know how to start but I would like to add the following features to the language :

- handling of parenthesis : so that sentences as `x = (2) ;` or `y = x - 2 * (3 / 4) ;` would be understood
- handling of functions : I would like to be able to define a function `f`.

For instance defining functions would be like this :

```
f(x)
{
    z = x + 2 ;
    ret z *z ;
};
```

(I would also like to be able to call functions inside functions.).

I don't know if I should declare type of the variables when declaring them, because I would also like later to define a date type as follows : `d = !20171112` for november the 12th, 2017, for instance.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and build your grammar first, using BNF, EBNF, etc. When you have a sense of the non-terminals and what rules they follow then you use those rules in your scanner to 'tokenize' and 'type' the lexemes appropriately.

Comment: Actually you're right, I will try use https://github.com/dabeaz/ply